# Grandma's Simple Puzzle Box

Tags: word, word-problem

One day, after a long morning walk, my Grandma came home with a box in her hand and told us the story of how she got it.

She said that she met six women in the park who were sitting together in a line. Five of them wore shirts of two different colors, but the last one wore only a single color. The group greeted her and placed the box in her hand, along with a piece of paper. They said that they had been trying to open the box for the last few days but hadn't managed it yet.

When Grandma showed me the box, I noticed some buttons to enter a word. The note she'd been given had this sequence of numbers written on it:

```
1   12   6   4   10   36   14   48   9   20   55
```

This must be a clue to identify the word. I'm sure it's a meaningful English word. Can someone help me open the box?

**Hint 1**

> You need to play with transformed digits and find the word hidden in this puzzle. Each number will transform individually and the nature of the numbers will help you in that.

Comment: Is it an actual english word or just a combination of letters?

Comment: Its an actual word and pretty simple ;)

Comment: Oh god, I can already feel the embarrassment when I find out how simple it would've been, but I just overthink everything...

Comment: i am thinking of a word but can't fully fit it into the code given

Comment: try with the additional info in the hint :)

Comment: communication is 13 letters, 5 letters repeated, u, a, t not repeated and now I give up :|

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Few easy steps to solve it:

> Original sequence:
>  1   12   6   4   10   36   14   48   9   20   55
>  Which i will divide with the simplest sequence:
>  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
>  =
>  1 6 2 1 2 6 2 6 1 2 5
>  And use hint:  "Five of them wears the two colors T-shirts but the last one wears the single color".
>  16 21 26 26 12 5
>  And that makes word:
>  p u z z l e

Comment: Good find! Its correct.