# Open a safe with the safe riddles

Tags: riddle

With the help of you great people, I was able to open [my Grandma's box](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53638/grandmas-simple-puzzle-box). She really appreciated it, and I am afraid I'll have to ask for your help again.

Grandma called me last night and told me that she was cleaning her backyard and found another safe. She also found a diary under it with this riddle on one of the pages.

> *Note: You will need to clear the rounds in order.*
>
> You can lie to me for 10 minutes.
>   You can recognize me for 10 minutes or
>   you can tie me with the commands.
>   I can be in line for 10 minutes,
>   I can be your partner or not, but
>   you love me always if I have bucks.
>   Find me and clear this round.
>
> Separate the figure and convert it to count,
>   put in the first place to clear next round.
>
> Remaining will, now, have no sense for you,
>   but convert it this to clear the last round too.

I understand that the safe should open in three rounds, but how? What do I need to enter? Can you please help me (and my Grandma, of course) to open the safe and discover what it is inside? I hope it's a winning lottery ticket worth a million dollars!

**Hint#1**

> Just noticed the page number on which these riddles are written. It's 54. It may help I think.

**Hint#2**

> 'C' found this character at the first page of the diary. May help to clear first round.

**Hint#3**

> Guys, I am thinking about the above hints and it seems that first round will need a word to clear. Whereas the next two round need some digits to pass.

**Hint#4**

> Digits/Number can be transformed to text to clear the first round.

**Hint#5**

> I am the most precious person while dealing for your business. Written somewhere in the diary. Not sure what this mean but seems a hint to clear the first round.

Comment: Looks like its a mobile phone.

Comment: I might chosen the wrong option to offer bounty i.e. "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.", but it should be "This question has not received enough attention.". Don't know how to update it, but this what i meant there.

Comment: The first round feels like it might be talking about playing cards. If you include two jokers like most packs do, there are 54 cards total. Lie (bluff), recognize (see / call), partner (solitaire). But the 10 minutes part doesn't seem to add up, so I'm probably wrong. I didn't put this under "Answer" because it's not an answer, however, I wish I was able to use the spoiler tag in comments to hide parts of this.

Comment: Agree with @Tony Youngblood, C54 also  related to a chess opening with some moves(Giuoco Piano). and theres also a 10 minute chess game

Comment: so much 10 minutes remind me of my alarm clock snooze....

Comment: A parking meter maybe?  You can lie to me for 10 minutes (grace period), you can pay and get "recognized" for 10 minutes and we always love parking meters with unused time (have bucks!).

Comment: Is the first word Star? becoz I love StarBucks..

Comment: nope @NaeemShaikh! ;)

Answer (score 1):

(Partial solution: sorry if it makes no sense)

I think the answer to first round is

> CHESS

As C54 is type of chess game starting with some moves(Giuoco Piano).

Now, convert it into numbers as second round gives:

> 3 8 5 19 19

Now, converting these numbers in letters separately and to binary makes no sense to me!

Comment: Good try! but not the correct word to pass the first round.

Comment: haha ok waiting for correct answer!!

Comment: Is it somehow related to scrimish or rushi games. these are also 10 minute games

Comment: Added a hint that might clear the things in first round.

Answer (score 0):

Seems for me as this is something related to

> BitCoins (10 minutes to create a page of a transaction which is going to be approved exactly in that time).

---

If we go this way, it might be:

> Convert BITCOIN into numbers by using letter number in alphabet: 2-9-19-3-15-9-14

Then it says that it makes no sense and something about first part.

> So maybe take "BIT" and convert it's number representation into binary?

---

> Then we have: 2919 which equals 101101100111 or 2-9-19 which should be: 10-1001-10011

Sorry if this makes no sense, I never played such kind of puzzles before. Just accidentally saw a link to puzzling.stackexchange :)

Comment: this exactly makes no sense, but good try :)

Answer (score 0):

I think its

> Captcha

as it start with "C".

Convert it to number and you get

> 3 1 16 20 3 8 1

Then its said to put in the first place,

I dont know it doesnt make any sense.

So I tried to remove the

> "C" from Captcha

and

> convert the remaining (aptcha) to Hex

to get

> 61 70 74 63 68 61

Answer (score -2):

Based on the first round findings,

> it could be a bank account number being given through clues.

As,

I can be your partner or not, but

> You need not be an account holder to access an online bank account

you can lie to me for 10 minutes.

> Usually allowed transaction time for online customers (on a rough approx.)

You can recognize me for 10 minutes or
you can tie me with the commands.
I can be in line for 10 minutes,

> describe the same as identified above

you love me always if I have bucks.

> One loves his/her account if it has some money !

And the page number 54 points to

> 28th February in a diary (by considering Saturdays and Sundays appear in a single page and there are no breaks between the months)...and perhaps this can be linked with the account number / access to account.

So the required account number could be

> 16212626125 is the obtained figure in the first puzzle and the counts obtained from it are as given

No. of 1s = 3

No. of 2s = 4

No. of 3s = 0

No. of 4s = 0

No. of 5s = 1 and

No. of 6s = 3

> so account number could be 340013 or something that can be derived based on the clues given in the 2nd para of this puzzle!

Comment: Sorry! but you are in wrong direction. You must see the tags to clear the first round.